# Label does not render the string "0" (Flex 4.5)

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, label, flex-spark

I was writing a custom chart component where. To add labels, I create a spark label and add it on screen. Although all other labels rendered, I noticed that the zero label does not render at all. Here's my code:

```
var invisibleTextField:TextField = new TextField();
var zeroLabel:spark.components.Label = new spark.components.Label();
zeroLabel.text = "0";
zeroLabel.name = "0Label";
invisibleTextField.text = " 0 ";
zeroLabel.width = invisibleTextField.textWidth;
zeroLabel.height = invisibleTextField.textHeight;
addChild(zeroLabel);
```

After multiple attempts, I figure that the label discards "0" as an empty string. I managed to workaround using spaces before and after the zero. Only one space would also do, but I needed center aligning. Anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: Most likely somewhere under the hood is doing "if(text)" and your 0 value returns false.  You'll probably have to pour over framework code to find it and fix it.  That said, giving a label a name that starts with a number is highly unusual.  Name (and ID) should usually follow the variable naming conventions.

Comment: Really? As far as AS3 goes, Boolean("0")==true

Comment: Why the TextField? Is it part of your work-around?

Comment: @sixfeetsix Good point on the TextField.  It is highly probably given the fact that the invisibleTextField is never added as a child, it has no height or width.

Comment: So, the label is actually there but its width and height values are perplexed.

Comment: @sixfeetsix I'm using the invisible TextField to obtain the character width of the text I need to use in the label. Just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There's a delay between text is filled into a text field and when it's dimensions are updated. Try using TextExtent instead of an invisible text field to do what you're doing.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextExtent.html